# Include specific directory level sublime project

Tags: css, project, less, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 have a project with the structure:

- public

  - vendors

    - a.css
    - b.css
  - myfile.less
  - myfile.css (compiled)

I am trying to exclude the css from the top level 'public' folder (ie. myfile.css) but I want to include the '.css' files from the vendors folders. I put ""file_exclude_patterns":["public/*.css"]" in my sublime-project file. But that excludes css from the vendors folders as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The `file_exclude_patterns` and `folder_exclude_patterns` selectors seem to only provide simple wildcard operations via `*`, as opposed to the regular expressions available in other settings. It doesn't help that the [project file documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html)  is sparse.

You have two general-case options here; both have their benefits and downsides, but neither will require you to specifically mention which files you want to exclude.

First, most documentation neglects mentioning the existence of `file_include_patterns` and `folder_include_patterns`. As long as you don't have many other file types present in your project directory, you can use something like the code below to include only the `css` files that are in the `vendors` directory. The downside is that you also have to tell Sublime Text everything that you *do* want to see, as opposed to everything that you *don't*, which might be a lot. **Using both `file_include_patterns` and `file_exclude_patterns` at the same time for a single folder doesn't work.**

```
"file_include_patterns": [
    "vendors/*.css",
    "*.less"
]
```

The other option, which works well if you prefer to use `Goto Anything` and don't care about how things look in the sidebar, is to just add the `vendors` subfolder as a separate entity in the `sublime-project` file and tailor per-folder settings accordingly. You'll probably end up with something like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "path/to/dev/public",
            "file_exclude_patterns": [
                "*.css"
            ],
            "folder_exclude_patterns": [
                "vendors"
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "path/to/public/vendors"
        }
    ]
}
```

Both methods feel hacky and convoluted—maybe sometime in the future we'll have the ability to use regular expressions to determine file exclusions.

Comment: Great answer. I logged an issue on the Sublime issue tracker, asking for better path support. I encourage anyone who cares about this issue to add their voice there. https://github.com/SublimeText/Issues/issues/332

Answer (score 0):

Won't this work?

```
"file_exclude_patterns":["public/myfile.css"]
```

Comment: Yes that does work. Thanks. I was hoping for a more general solution that would hide all files just in that folder and not the sub folders so I don't need to specify them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "path": "public/vendors"
    },
    {
      "file_exclude_patterns": [
        "*.css"
      ],
      "folder_exclude_patterns": [
        "*"
      ],
      "path": "public"
    }
  ]
}
```